# Spring 3 autowire is always null

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm having difficultly getting what seems like a very basic auto wiring to occur. I'm trying to add another data source to our system for warehouse stuff, but I'm running in to an issue. I'm not an expert in Spring by an stretch, and I've been reading around on this issue, and it seems like I have everything setup correctly.

I tried changing my component scan to also include the repositories, but that didn't fix the issue. I also tried @Resource with the bean name specified.

It never throws any errors until I try to construct the jdbcTemplate since the dataSource is null.

The other classes we have that use injection all seem to work fine, it's just this new one using the datasource injection is failing (This is the first time we're doing a datasource injection, everything else is all Domain entities, but we won't be using a traditional domain/entity for the warehouse db).

I feel certain I'm just missing something very simple, but so far I haven't been able to find what that is.

Just a debug repo

```
package com.foobar.repositories

@Repository
public class WarehouseRepository
{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource warehouseDataSource; // This is always null

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public WarehouseRepository()
    {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(warehouseDataSource);
    }

    public void debug()
    {
        SqlRowSet sqlRowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("select * from foobar");
        int i = sqlRowSet.getInt(0);
        String test = sqlRowSet.getString(1);
    }
}
```

XML Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd"
        >
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.foobar.domain"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.foobar.services"/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.foobar.repositories" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

        <bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:env.properties"/>
        </bean>
        <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
              destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClass" value="${env.driver}" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${env.url}" />
            <property name="user" value="${env.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${env.password}" />
            <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
            <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
            <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
            <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="JpaPersistenceUnit" />
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
                    <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
                    <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="warehouseDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${env.driver}" />
            <property name="url" value="${env.warehouseUrl}" />
            <property name="username" value="${env.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${env.password}" />
        </bean>

</beans>
```

Stack trace:

```
Sep 17, 2013 6:50:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcAccessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.<init>(JdbcTemplate.java:165)
    at com.foobar.repositories.WarehouseRepository.debug(WarehouseRepository.java:23)
    at com.services.publicServices.OrderConfirmationService.debug(OrderConfirmationService.java:79)
    at com.services.publicServices.OrderConfirmationService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$fd3be016.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:627)
    at com.services.publicServices.OrderConfirmationService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f00e6716.debug(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Repo method after removing the constructor

```
package com.foobar.repositories

@Repository
public class WarehouseRepository
{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource warehouseDataSource; // This is always null

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;   

    public void debug()
    {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(warehouseDataSource);// Still blows up here
        SqlRowSet sqlRowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("select * from foobar");
        int i = sqlRowSet.getInt(0);
        String test = sqlRowSet.getString(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you obtaining a reference to the `WarehouseRepository` instance?

Comment: For my test purposes I was just manually creating it (new WarehouseRepository())

Comment: That's your problem. If it's not a bean, Spring doesn't autowire it.

Comment: I also tried removing the constructor and just calling the debug() function, but the same result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring's autowiring is only applied to container-managed beans, not to instances created directly with `new`, which Spring doesn't know about. Instead of calling `new WarehouseRepository()`, declare the bean in a configuration file (XML or Java), or register the bean programmatically (which is possible but a pain).

Answer (score -5):

you need a public getter and setter for

```
private DataSource warehouseDataSource;
```

Comment: Autowiring doesn't require getters and setters. It directly sets the field through reflection.