# @Autowire not preperly injected with Spring @Bean configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I am practising on spring-social and it seems that the userConnectionRepository is not properly autowired in the following code when I do a "Run as Junit Test" in Eclipse. I get a Null pointer exception on the usersConnectionRepository when creating a new FacebookOffLine although breakpoints put in the @Bean java creation code shows that they seem to be properly created. Thanks in advance,

```
public class FacebookOffline {

    private Facebook fb;

    @Autowired
    private UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository;

    public FacebookOffline(User user) {
        super();

        ConnectionRepository cr = usersConnectionRepository.createConnectionRepository(user.getId());
        fb = cr.getPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class).getApi();
    }

}
```

Here is the test code :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        org.springframework.social.quickstart.config.MainConfig.class,
        org.springframework.social.quickstart.config.SocialConfig.class })
public class FacebookOfflineTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        FacebookOffline essai = new FacebookOffline(new User("yves"));
```

And the Spring configuration classes adapted from Keith Donald Quick Start Sample :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.springframework.social.quickstart", excludeFilters = { @Filter(Configuration.class) })
@PropertySource("classpath:org/springframework/social/quickstart/config/application.properties")
public class MainConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource toReturn = new DriverManagerDataSource("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_social");
        toReturn.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        toReturn.setUsername("spring");
        toReturn.setPassword("spring");
        return toReturn;

    }
}

@Configuration
public class SocialConfig {

    @Inject
    private Environment environment;

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
        ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
        registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(environment
                .getProperty("facebook.clientId"), environment
                .getProperty("facebook.clientSecret")));
        return registry;
    }

@Bean
    public UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository() {
        JdbcUsersConnectionRepository repository = new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(
                dataSource, connectionFactoryLocator(), Encryptors.noOpText());
        return repository;
    }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring 3 autowire is always null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861094/spring-3-autowire-is-always-null)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually there are 2 problems here.

1. Spring cannot autowire beans it doesn't control (i.e. created with new)
2. Dependencies aren't available in the constructor (an object instance is needed before it can be injected)

The first one can be mitigated by letting spring manage an instance of FacebookOffline (or if you need multiple instances make the bean request or session scoped).

The second is a bit harder but can probaly solved by using a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` (or by implementing `InitializingBean` from spring).

Comment: Thanks, this was the right things to do. Splitting the constructor whith the second part as an initmethod annotated by @PostConstruct made it work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You did

```
FacebookOffline essai = new FacebookOffline(new User("yves"));
```

That means, Spring isn't managing this `essai` instance and thus spring can't autowire any variables in the `essai`.

You'll have to create bean of `FacebookOffline` in `SocialConfig`.

Then you can have

```
/* ... */
public class FacebookOfflineTest {

@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

@Test
public void test1() {
    FacebookOffline essai = context.getBean(FacebookOffline.class);
```

OR

```
 /* ... */
public class FacebookOfflineTest {

@Autowired
FacebookOffline essai;

@Test
public void test1() {
    // You can use essai now
```

Also, you'll need to update `FacebookOffline` as Dependencies ain't available in constructor.

```
public class FacebookOffline {

private Facebook fb;

@Autowired
private UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository;

public FacebookOffline(User user) {
    super();  
}

@PostConstruct
void loadFacebook() {
    ConnectionRepository cr =       usersConnectionRepository.createConnectionRepository(user.getId());
     fb = cr.getPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class).getApi();
   }
}
```

Comment: Tried the second part but it did not change anything, the usersConnectionRepository has still not been instantiated. Looks like the 3rd answer to the post is giving a potential good reason for taht

Comment: Yea, I totally missed that you're doing it in constructor. I'll update my answer and you can try.

Answer (score 0):

Spring can't autowire fields on an instance you create via `new` since it doesn't know about it. Declare a bean of type `FacebookOffline` instead.

Comment: Ok, but does that mean it should not still autowire the UsersConnectionRepository which is what I really need?

Comment: @YvesNicolas I clarified my answer; Spring can't autowire fields on an object it doesn't know about (your `FacebookOffline`, which you're creating via `new` instead of as a Spring bean).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, looks like the good path to follow. Will do a few tests around that.